# How to install app on android with gradlew.sh?

Tags: android, linux, installation

I have downloaded an android app from Github ([Link](https://github.com/aqibsaeed/Human-Activity-Recognition-using-CNN/tree/master/ActivityRecognition)). But I am unable to install this app on android (I am using Linux). Could someone tell me which direction should I go? 
App folder Contains following files:

1. build.gradle
2. gradle.properties
3. gradlew
4. gradlew.bat
5. settings.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first install gradle [this linke](https://gradle.org/install/#with-a-package-manager)
then you can build the project on Command Line './gradlew assembleDebug'
This creates an APK named module_name-debug.apk in project_name/module_name/build/outputs/apk/. The file is already signed with the debug key and aligned with zipalign, so you can immediately install it on a device.